# complex queries in sql

Tags: sql

```
select E.eid from Employee E
    where E.salary = (
        select max (E2.salary) from Employee E2
            where E2.salary ≠ (
                select max (E3.salary) from Employee E3);
```

How is the above query proccessed ? 
What does this query return ?
What is the order of proccesing of the sub-queries ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Furthest in first.  It finds the highest salary as E3 first, then finds the highest that isn't that (the second highest), then finds employees that match that second highest salary.

So that would return the id of any employee that has the second highest ranked salary (ties behave in such a way that everyone with the top salary would be eliminated at the E2 level returning everyone with the second highest salary).

I suspect you're getting downvotes because this was trivial to check on sqlfiddle, which also would have shown your syntax errors (didn't close all the brackets).

Here is a fiddle of it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a7d18/6

Comment: Not concerned about the syntax.Just want to be clear with the functioning of the statements. In case of an aggegate function,are the records first fetched and then the aggregate is calculated ?

Comment: I think the easiest way to describe it would be : It tries to evaluate the first part (e.salary = X) but then has to calculate the inner (X), then it tries to calculate the second part (E2.salary <> Y) but then has to calculate that inner (Y), so it calculates the furthest in (Y), then can evaluate the next level (X), then can finally return the outermost.  In terms of first fetching then aggregating, assuming default locking, it is fetching, but not letting anyone change the values while it finishes everything else.  It doesn't pre-fetch, it just figures out each query as a complete action.